# Optimization on fixed sum

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider this following scenario. Suppose I have $N$ cents, and I want to dispatch these money to $n$ people, each got $x_i$ cents. In order to simplify this problem, we assume the cents are "divisable", which means $x_i$ can be any non-negtive real number($x_i>=0, x_i\in R$)

For any one got the money, will have some kind of "happiness index" which is directly related to the money he just got, we defined it as $f_i(x_i)$, which means different people may have different "happiness functions"

Then, here is the problem:

How can I properly divide theses money in order to got the maximum sum of "happiness index"?

$$
\max_{i=1,2,..n} \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i) \quad s.t \quad \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} = N,\quad x_i \in [0,N]
$$

Here $f_i(x_i)$ is a bunch of functions, which may have some same kind of forms(but with respective parameter, for example $f_i(x_i) = N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$ or so.

Is there any mature optimization algorithms for this specific kinds of problem(rather than some more general ones)?

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: The objective function is supposed to be a real-valued function. What do you mean by maximizing $n$ functions?

Comment: sorry, it's a typo. I want to maximize the sum of these functions

Comment: Is $f_{i}(x_{i})$ a probability density function? if does, take a look at stochastic optimization methods.

Comment: @AlexSilva $f_i(x_i)$ is monotone increasing, the more money some people got, the happier he will be. An example might be cumulative distribution function.

Comment: @Benson, ok. But, if your function is not deterministic, you should use stochastic methods.

Comment: @AlexSilva the function is not given, but you may suppose I've already known every function's format. Currently. I decide to model people's reaction to rewards using *erf* functions which is CDF of normal distribution(each people with different parameters of course), but I might try other different families of functions afterwards.

Comment: @Benson, Firstly, you should know that the $erf$ function can be viewed as a CDF only in probability domain. If you use just the expression, it is not a non-deterministic problem, then you can use several different methods depending on the objective function. Second, why  do you use the $erf$ function? Why not just an affine function like $ f_{i}(x_{i}) = w_{i}x_{i}$, where $w_{i} > 0$ is a sort of satisfied level for the person $i$? In this case, you will have a LP problem, which is easier to solve.